# sage notebook dirac bra-ket notation with latex

Tags: latex, sympy, mathjax, sage

I'm having difficulty getting properly formatted latex output for  notation in the sage notebook.  I am using sympy for sympy.physics.quantum.Bra and Ket, but cant seem to get proper latex behaviour out of them.

for instance, I want to show the symbol psi in a ket.

```
sage: p = var('Psi')
sage: show(p)
```

displays the greek character {\Psi}

but using sympy

```
sage: k = Ket(p)
sage: show(k)
```

displays plain text |Psi>

I have searched, tested and experimented to try and get formatted output, to no avail.

```
sage: latex(k)
```

{\left|\Psi\right\rangle} - plain text

creating a custom latex macro:

```
sage: from sage.misc.latex import latex_extra_preamble
sage: latex.add_macro("\\newcommand{\\ket}[1]{\\left|{#1}\\right\\rangle}")
sage: var("myket", latex_name=r"\ket{\alpha}")
sage: show(myket)
```

gives the output i want! latex style ket with the symbol for alpha...
however, as soon as I try to apply this method to the sympy Ket, it fails

```
sage: k = Ket('k', latex_name=r"\left|{\Psi}\right\rangle")
sage: show(k)
```

and other variants, all spit out plain-text |k>

I have a feeling that there is a simple solution for this, some flag that i'm missing to get sympy to behave properly in sage notebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution. It is probably not very robust but it could probably be adapted to your need. They are two problems here:

1 -  You need to tell sage how to latex Bra and Ket. This can be done using `latex_table` which is a dict associating type to latex type-setting functions:

```
from sympy.physics.quantum import Bra, Ket
def latexBra(x):
    if len(x.args) == 1:  # x.args contains the argument of the Bra
        res = latex(x.args[0])
    else:
        res = ",".join(latex(i) for i in x.args)
    return r"{\left|%s\right\rangle}"%res

from sage.misc.latex import latex_table
latex_table[Bra] = latexBra
```

Of course you have to do the same for Ket. You probably want to do that also for

```
sympy.physics.quantum.operator.OuterProduct
sympy.physics.quantum.operator.InnerProduct
...
```

However, this only solve part of the problem: latexing the Bra. Note that Phi isn't latexed.

```
sage: bPhi = Bra(var('Phi'))
sage: print latex(bPhi)
{\left|\text{\texttt{Phi}}\right\rangle}
```

2 - The reason is that Sympy `bPhi` argument `bPhi.args[0]` is not exactly the Sage variable `Phi` but a Sympy `Symbol` object:

```
sage: type(bPhi.args[0])
<class 'sympy.core.symbol.Symbol'>
```

However one can get back Sage's `Phi` by coercing the `Symbol` object back to Sage's symbolic ring (`SR`):

```
sage: SR(bPhi.args[0]) is Phi
True
```

So you can do tell Sage to to that for latexing Sympy's `Symbol`:

```
from sympy.core.symbol import Symbol
latex_table[Symbol] = lambda x : latex(SR(x))
```

And then:

```
sage: bPhi = Bra(var('Phi'))
sage: print latex(bPhi)
{\left|\Phi\right\rangle}
```

Comment: Just to make sure I understand; is the latex_table just the proper way to add arbitrary latex formatting to any object we want to display?  like a way to create latex wrappers for objects?

something i noticed:
    sage: bPhi = Bra(var('Phi'))
    sage: print latex(bPhi)
    {\left\langle \Phi\right|} 
that is a little weird, but not a concern for me because...
    sage: bPhi
gives me the latex Bra with the expected symbol for Phi!
    sage: type(bPhi.args[0])
    <class'sympy.core.symbol.Symbol'>
which I think will work for my purposes.

Comment: @Locky1138: `latex_table` doesn't associate latex formatting to objects but to `type` (=class). Any object of type `Bra` will use the `latex_table[Bra]` formatting function. This is an alternative to defining a method `_latex_` in class `Bra`. You have to use it if you can't modify the class (eg: for builtin class). Also, I don't understand what you find weird.

Comment: print latex(bPhi) => {\left\langle \Phi\right|} just has a blank space, instead of any character or latex command. I was expecting {\left|\text{\texttt{Phi}}\right\rangle} from your example.

Comment: You can use `sympy.latex` to get the latex representation of the bra and ket.